# implementing oracle query to powerbuilder

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder

I have difficulty in implementing Oracle query to powerbuilder. I have 3 singeline edit the name is : 
1. sle_merk
2. sle_tipe
3. sle_jns

and I have oracle query

```
select b.nm_merk
,      c.keterangan
,      c.tipe
,      b.keterangan
,      c.usrid
,      c.otr
,      c.dupd
,      c.dotr
,      c.status
from   tipe_kend c 
left 
outer
join   jns_kendaraan b 
on     c.kd_jenis = b.kd_jenis
left 
outer
join   merk_kend b 
on     c.kd_merk = b.kd_merk
where  b.kd_jenis like '%%' 
AND    b.kd_merk  like '%%' 
AND    c.tipe     like '%%'
```

what I want is if all singeline edit is null then the data is appears, but when one of singeline edit is filled then the data is appears where data like     %singelineedit%. I have difficulty in implementing the query into Powerbuilder.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the problem?

Comment: You are using the table alias `b` twice: `jns_kendaraan b`, `merk_kend b`. This has nothing to do with powerbuilder, however.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say you are using a datawindow control I will assume you are not.  With that being said then this must be a piece of embedded SQL inside some method.  As such you need to declare variables for each of the columns in your retrieve.  You also need variables to hold the contents of the SLE controls.

You would end up with something like this:

```
string ls_nm // make sure datatypes are correct
string ls_sle1, ls_sle2, ls_sle3
// get values of the sle controls
ls_sle1 = sle_merk.text
IF IsNull(ls_sle1) THEN ls_sle1 = ''
ls_sle2 = sle_tipe.text
IF IsNull(ls_sle2) THEN ls_sle2 = ''
ls_sle3 = sle_jns.text
IF IsNull(ls_sle3) THEN ls_sle3 = ''

select b.nm_merk, ... 
INTO :ls_nm, ...
from   tipe_kend c 
left outer join ns_kendaraan b on c.kd_jenis = b.kd_jenis
left outer join   merk_kend b on  c.kd_merk = b.kd_merk
where  b.kd_jenis like '%' + ls_sle1 + '%' 
AND    b.kd_merk  like '%' + ls_sle2 + '%' 
AND    c.tipe     like '% + ls_sle3 + '%';
```

Note this will FAIL if more than a single row is returned.  If you need multiple rows you need to use a datawindow/datastore control (or cursors but they are very inefficient).